# how to sort gridview based on drop down list selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I need the gridview to be displayed based on the dropdownlist : LastestTransactionFirst, EarlierTransactionFirst. So basically it's desc or asc based on the date in gridview. May i know how should i go about it ?

This is my code for gridview selection. But I had a dropdownlist and need the gridview to appear based on the dropdownlist selection.

```
    myConnection.ConnectionString = strConnectionString;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT thDate, thType, thAmountIn, thAmountOut from [Transaction] ORDER BY thDate, thType, thAmountIn, thAmountOut DESC", myConnection);
    myConnection.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    GridView1.DataSource = reader1;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of sorting in gridview

```
DataView dvItems = new DataView((DataTable)ds.Tables["datatable1"]);

 if (ddl_itemsorderby.SelectedValue == "MenuGroup")
     dvItems.Sort = "Menu_Group, Item_Name ASC";
 else if (ddl_itemsorderby.SelectedValue == "Item")
     dvItems.Sort = "Item_Name, Menu_Group ASC";
 else if (ddl_itemsorderby.SelectedValue == "Rate")
     dvItems.Sort = "Item_rate, Item_Name ASC";
 else if (ddl_itemsorderby.SelectedValue == "Quantity")
     dvItems.Sort = "Item_Quantity, Item_Name ASC";

 gridview1.DataSource = dvItems;
 gridview1.DataBind();
```

Here Menu_Group,Item_name ... are the column names  in the datatable which you bind to the gridview.

"Menu_Group, Item_Name ASC" This means that The forse order prority will be given to the Menu_Group first and second order priority will be given to Item_Name. 
  ASC is the Order type will be ascending

ddl_itemsorderby is the dropdownlist from which the column order will be selected.
dvitems is the dataview.

ASC is the ascending order.

You have to create a dataview containing the data in the datatable and then sort the values in the dataview and then bind the dataview to the gridview

Comment: hi, the datatable1 is it the table in the database? May i know where to put this coding? is it in the 
protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) ?

Comment: the datatable is the table which you bind your data to the gridview
it is not the database table
yo will be fetching the data from the database into a datatable in order to bind it to the gridview

Comment: You have to write the code either in dropdownlist selected index changed (If you do this you have to use update panel)
or else place a button beside the drop downlist and write this code in button click event of the button

Comment: Do one thing 
Declare these two statements on the top of your  project.  
   "SqlDataAdapter da;"
   "DataSet ds = new DataSet();"
 Just below your namespace ie (below public class ....)
 Then, After you write "myConnection.Open();" write "da.Fill(ds, "datatable1");"then write "myConnection.Close();"
Here "ds" is the dataset and "datatable1" is the datatable.

Comment: hi, however my dropdownlist value should be : LastestTransactionFirst, EarlierTransactionFirst and not the names from the data table.

Comment: After you do what i said ie after "myConnection.close();" is done write the code i said on the top.
In that Menu_Group have to be replaced by thDate if you want to order your table by date

Comment: hi, but I'm having an error. They said
'DataTable must be set prior to using DataView.'

Comment: Do you mind telling me how to solve again. I had the same error again.

Comment: Having the same error.. Data table must be set to prior again.. I don't know why. Sigh!

Comment: That sql query is for the radio button, however the dropdownlist is not working now. Not to mention the radio button.

Comment: It works only after the radio button is selected. The process done is when you select the radio button, the data is retrieved from the database and attached to the datatable then when the dropdownlist is selected the data is sorted and then binded to the gridview.

Answer (score 1):

1) You can use [Dynamic Order By](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/dynamic-order-by) in your query preferably using a stored procedure

2) Quick & dirty way would be passing the selectedValue on your dropdown list selected index changed event & re-binding your gridview, also enable autopostback to true on the dropdown list. Something like

```
protected void yourDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   BindYourGridView(yourDropDown.SelectedValue);  
}

BindYourGridView(string sortParam)
{
   string orderBy=null;
   switch sortParam
   {
         case 0:
             orderBy= "ORDER BY thDate, thType, thAmountIn, thAmountOut DESC"
             break;
         case 1:
             orderBy= "ORDER BY thDate, thType, thAmountIn, thAmountOut"
             break;   
   }
  string yourQuery= "Select columns from table "+ orderBy;
  // Your data access code
  // Bind your gridview
}


//ASPX
   <asp:DropDownList ID="yourDropDownList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
   <asp:ListItem Text="Recent First" Value="0" />
   <asp:ListItem Text="Earlier First" Value="1" />
   </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: BindYourGridView(Convert.ToInt32(yourDropDown.SelectedValue));
hi, the BindYourGridView, is it GridView1?